# Openpyxl: How to get user data and fill a spreadseet in with results of the math?

Tags: python, excel, python-3.6

I am really new to the coding world but wanted to create a python program that would figure the following:
1. user inputs Starting Elevation and % of Fall to the pipe, the length of the pipe, and what elevation should be every 10 feet along the route.
I have figured how to capture this data however when I get to having python do the calculations and fill the remaining cells / columns in I have no idea what to do to make this happen.

Any help is appreciated. 
This is what i have so far and it works I just can not figure out how to make it perform and write the calculations to complete the spreadsheet.

```
import openpyxl
from openpyxl import workbook
wb = openpyxl.load_workbook ('slope.xlsx', data_only = True)

ws1 = wb['cover']


# Beginning Elevation
print (' What is the Starting Elevation?')
x = eval(input(""))

# Slope of Pipe 
print ('What % slope do you wish to hold?')
y = eval(input(""))

#Length of Run
print ('What is the Length of the Run?')
z = eval(input(""))

# Fall of Pipe Length x Percentage Elevation Change 
v =(y*z)
print (v)

# Ending Elevation Will be 
w=(x+v)
print (w)

# How Many 10 foot segments in Run
t=(z/10)
print(t)

# Fall per Stick 
#10 Foot Pipe 
l=(v/t)

# Column Labels based on length of Pipe

if z>100:
    ws1['A14'] = "0+00"
if z>199:
    ws1['A15'] = "1+00"
if z>299:
    ws1['A16'] = "2+00"
if z>399:
    ws1['A17'] = "3+00"
if z>499:
    ws1['a18'] ="4+00"
if z>599:
    ws1['a19'] = "5+00"
if z>699:
    ws1['a20'] = "6+00"


ws1['c14'] =x+l
ws1['c15'] ='c14'+l




# Append Cells in Worksheet with the calculations of above 
ws1['k8'] = y
ws1['c8'] = x
ws1['h8'] = w
ws1['n10'] = t
ws1['k10'] = v
ws1['n8'] = z
ws1['q9'] = l





# Save Workbook as 
wb.save('slope_results5.xlsx')
```

Comment: In this code everything works fine except line `ws1['c15'] ='c14'+l`. It should be changed to `ws1['c15'] =x+l+l` or `ws1['c15'] = "=C14 + %f" % l`if you want to use excel formula.

Comment: thanks for the response,

Answer (score 0):

So let me clarify the question here:
So i had been working on this for almost a month now, not being a programmer i am sure it is something simple i am missing. 
I have the code performing the calculations i want now and want to take that data and enter to an excel spreadsheet. The program runs fine saves the workbook with the appointed name, however the Spreadsheet when i open it is blank (contains none of the data that was calculated). I can assign certain values to specific cells however this program data needs to complete an spreadsheet between row 13 and column C. I had included my latest code in order for some input from you that are more familiar with the coding.

```
    import openpyxl
import xlsxwriter
from datetime import *
from openpyxl import workbook
wb = openpyxl.load_workbook('C:\Python\Good_script\slope.xlsx', data_only = True)
ws1 = wb['Cover']



    # Define  Station Information
    station_start = 0
    station_segment = 100
    station_step = 0
    pipe_length = 0
    labels = pipe_length

# User Input values
print("What is the Starting Elevation?")
elev_start = float(input(''))
#-------------------------------------------------
print("What is the total Length of the Run?")
total_length = float(input(''))
#--------------------------------------------------
print("What Length of Pipe are you installing?")
pipe_length = int(input(''))
#--------------------------------------------------
print("What Percentage of slope are you wanting to carry?")
slope_total = float(input(''))
#--------------------------------------------------
# Program Displays input information 
print("To Verify your input the following:")
print("Starting Elevation is:",elev_start)
print("|==============================================|\n\n")
print("The total Length of the run is:",total_length)
print("|==============================================|\n\n")
print("The Pipe Joints are:", pipe_length,"Feet sticks")
print("|==============================================|\n\n")
print("So you wish to carry a",slope_total,"% Slope")
print("|==============================================|\n\n")

# Program Calculates remaining information 
total_pipe = total_length / pipe_length
total_fall = total_length * slope_total
end_elev = elev_start + total_fall
station_start = 0
station_segment = 100
station_step = 0
drop_per_pipe = total_fall / total_pipe
current_length= 0
station_elevation = elev_start

row_max = 100
col_max = 13

# Program displays calculated information
print("Total Fall for this Run =",total_fall,"Feet")
print("Projected End Elevation =",end_elev, "Feet above Sea Level")
print("Station Step will be +",pipe_length)
print("Starting elevation at first stick will be",station_start)
print("Each Joint of pipe will change",drop_per_pipe,"tenths/hundredths")
print("Total Sticks of pipe to complete:",total_pipe)
#========================================================================LOOPS
while current_length< total_length:
    print("|** Current station @  %s" % current_length)
    print("Station | " + str(station_start) + "+" + "0" + str(station_step) + " | " + str(station_elevation))
    station_elevation = station_elevation + drop_per_pipe
    station_step = station_step + pipe_length
    while (0 < station_step < station_segment) and (station_elevation != end_elev):
        print("Station | " + str(station_start) + "+" + str(station_step) + " | " + str(station_elevation))
        station_elevation = station_elevation + drop_per_pipe
        station_step = station_step + pipe_length

    current_length = current_length + station_segment
    station_start = station_start +1
    station_step = 0

print("|** Current station @  %s" % current_length)
print("Station | " + str(station_start) + "+" + "0" + str(station_step) + " | " + str(station_elevation))   

   # other code below that is not relevant to this question like save workbook as file-name below
```

Comment: Oh almost forgot the information needed to populate spreadsheet is within the While Statements

Comment: Update: I now have it populating the sheet but the print to screen numbers are correct but the ones written to the spreadsheet are not? what or how do i fix this?